# gdb debugging stripped executables

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, stripping

I have an executable provided as is. The creators have compiled it with minimal dependencies and no symbols. When I load it in gdb it sais:

```
...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

I would like to do step-by-step debugging in the assembler code with the optional exit point in case the execution does leave the shared executable. The reason I need this is because I have an executable which segfaults and I have no other means of tackling the problem.

I have created a minimalist example (simple.c++):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and compile it with:

```
g++ -static -O3 simple.c++ -o simple
strip simple
```

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to do step-by-step debugging in the assembler code

What is stopping you from doing just that?

`readelf -h a.out` will tell you what address the `start` is at. Set a breakpoint there and continue with `stepi` or `nexti`.

This will actually take a *really long time*, so a more efficient approach might be go backwards from the crash point, rather than forward from `start`. That is, run the binary until crash point, then figure out how you got there, set a breakpoint earlier, and re-run. [Reverse debugging](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html) may also help.

Comment: I have also found a front-end which can debug the assembler code for me. https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger